# SAX parser doesn't follow references

Tags: xsd, sax, saxparser

I am trying to parse an HL7 message definition from xsd. I have my schema definition split up between two files. First file contains actual message definition and the second contains segment definitions within the message.

I am trying to tweak an example code to parse XML from here https://gist.github.com/helderdarocha/8791651. I don't understand why SAX parser doesn't follow references.

Here are two examples of my xsd definitions.

First file has the following definition

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
           targetNamespace="http://www.xsd_porcessor.org/parser" 
           xmlns="http://www.xsd_porcessor.org/parser" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

           <xs:include schemaLocation="segments.xsd"/>

           <xs:complexType name="ADT.01.MESSAGE">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="MSH"/>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="EVN"/>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="PID"/>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="PV1"/>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="IN1"/>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="IN2"/>
                </xs:sequence>
           </xs:complexType>
           <xs:element name="ADT.A01" type="ADT.01.MESSAGE"/>
</xs:schema>
```

The second file has the following header

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
           targetNamespace="http://www.xsd_porcessor.org/parser" 
           xmlns="http://www.xsd_porcessor.org/parser" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
```

...and a multitude segment definitions represented as complexTypes. Bellow is example of one

```
   <xs:complexType name="MSH.SEGMENT">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="MSH.1.FieldSeparator"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="MSH.2.ServiceString"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="MSH.3.SendingApplication"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" ref="MSH.4.SendingFacility"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" ref="MSH.5.ReceivingApplication"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" ref="MSH.6.ReceivingFacility"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="MSH.7.DateTimeOfMessage"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" ref="MSH.8.Security"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="MSH.9.MessageType"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="MSH.10.MessageControlID"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="MSH.11.ProcessingID"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="MSH.12.VersionID"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" ref="MSH.13.SequenceNumber"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" ref="MSH.14.ContinuationPointer"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" ref="MSH.15.AcceptAcknowledgmentType"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" ref="MSH.16.ApplicationAcknowledgmentType"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" ref="MSH.17.CountryCode"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" ref="MSH.18.CharacterSet"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" ref="MSH.19.PrincipalLanguageOfMessage"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" ref="MSH.20.AlternateCharacterSetHandlingScheme"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" ref="MSH.21.MessageProfileIdentifier"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" ref="MSH.22.SendingResponsibleOrganization"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" ref="MSH.23.ReceivingResponsibleOrganization"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" ref="MSH.24.SendingNetworkAddress"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" ref="MSH.25.ReceivingNetworkAddress"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>  
    <xs:element name="MSH" type="MSH.SEGMENT"/>
```

Here is a tweaked parser itself

```
package ca.parser.xml;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.parsers.*;

import org.xml.sax.*;

import org.xml.sax.helpers.*;

public class SAXReaderExample {

    public static final String PATH = "resources";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader reader = sp.getXMLReader();
        reader.setContentHandler(new SchemaSaxHandler());
        reader.parse(new InputSource(new FileInputStream(new File(PATH, "messages.xsd"))));
    }
}


class SchemaSaxHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    // temporary - always null when tag closes
    private String currentSimpleTypeName;
    private String currentSimpleTypeBaseType;
    private SchemaElement currentElement;
    private SchemaComplexType currentComplexType;
    private List<SchemaElement> currentSequence;

    // cumulative - will use the data when XML finishes
    private Map<String, String> simpleTypes = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<String, SchemaComplexType> complexTypes = new HashMap<>();
    private SchemaElement rootElement;

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {

        if (qName.equals("xs:simpleType")) {
            currentSimpleTypeName = atts.getValue("name");
        }
        if (qName.equals("xs:restriction")) {
            currentSimpleTypeBaseType = atts.getValue("base");
        }

        if (qName.equals("xs:complexType")) {
            currentComplexType = new SchemaComplexType();

            currentComplexType.setName(atts.getValue("name"));
        }

        if (qName.equals("xs:sequence")) {
            currentSequence = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        if (qName.equals("xs:element")) {
            currentElement = new SchemaElement();
            if (atts.getValue("name")==null) {
                currentElement.setName(atts.getValue("ref"));
            }else {
                currentElement.setName(atts.getValue("name"));
            }
            currentElement.setType(atts.getValue("type"));
            currentElement.setReference(atts.getValue("ref"));
             if (currentSequence != null) {
                currentSequence.add(currentElement);
            } else {
                rootElement = currentElement;
            }
        }

        if (qName.equals("xs:attribute")) {
            currentComplexType.addAttribute(atts.getValue("name"), atts.getValue("type"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        if (qName.equals("xs:simpleType")) {
            simpleTypes.put(currentSimpleTypeName, currentSimpleTypeBaseType);
            currentSimpleTypeName = null;
            currentSimpleTypeBaseType = null;
        }
        if (qName.equals("xs:complexType")) {
            complexTypes.put(currentComplexType.getName(), currentComplexType);
            currentComplexType = null;
        }
        if (qName.equals("xs:sequence")) {
            if (currentComplexType != null) {
                currentComplexType.setChildren(currentSequence);
            }
            currentSequence = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
        makeTree(rootElement);
        printTree(rootElement, "");
    }

    public void makeTree(SchemaElement element) {
        SchemaComplexType type = complexTypes.get(element.getType());
        if (type != null) {
            List<SchemaElement> children = type.getChildren();
            element.setChildren(children);
            for (SchemaElement child : children) {
                makeTree(child);
            }
            element.setAttributes(type.getAttributes());
        } else {
            element.setType(simpleTypes.get(element.getType()));
        }
    }

    private void printTree(SchemaElement element, String indent) {
        System.out.println(indent + element.getName() + " : " + element.getType());
        Map<String, String> attributes = element.getAttributes();
        if (attributes != null) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : attributes.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("    @" + entry.getKey() + " : " + simpleTypes.get(entry.getValue()));
            }
        }
        List<SchemaElement> children = element.getChildren();
        if (children != null) {
            for (SchemaElement child : children) {
                printTree(child, indent + "    ");
            }
        }
    }
    class SchemaElement {

        private String name;
        private String type;
        private String reference;
        public String getReference() {
            return reference;
        }
        public void setReference(String reference) {
            this.reference = reference;
        }
        private List<SchemaElement> children;
        private Map<String, String> attributes;
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }
        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }
        public List<SchemaElement> getChildren() {
            return children;
        }
        public void setChildren(List<SchemaElement> children) {
            this.children = children;
        }
        public Map<String, String> getAttributes() {
            return attributes;
        }
        public void setAttributes(Map<String, String> attributes) {
            this.attributes = attributes;
        }


    }

    class SchemaComplexType {        
        private String name;
        private String reference;
        private List<SchemaElement> children;
        private Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<>();
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public List<SchemaElement> getChildren() {
            return children;
        }
        public void setChildren(List<SchemaElement> children) {
            this.children = children;
        }
        public Map<String, String> getAttributes() {
            return attributes;
        }
        public void setAttributes(Map<String, String> attributes) {
            this.attributes = attributes;
        }

        public String getReference() {
            return reference;
        }

        public void setReference(String reference) {
            this.reference=reference;
        }

        public void addAttribute(String name,String type) {
            attributes.put(name, type);
        }
    }
```

Any ideas what is going? You help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: how familiar are you with sax parsing? Are you a first time user of it?

Comment: I used it a LONG time ago and never with XSD. Why does it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like there are two separate concepts at work here.

If a validating SAX parser is being used to parse a piece of XML, and validate it against *its* schema:

```
<xmlRootElement
    xmlns="http://www.xsd_porcessor.org/parser"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.xsd_porcessor.org/parser messages.xsd">
```

... etc, then clearly when that schema was resolved behind the scenes, the parser would need to follow any references and imports in there.

However if the `.xsd` itself is the XML being parsed, then as you've already found, it's elements will be directly passed into the `ContentHandler`.  The `SchemaSaxHandler` above will need to do some more work to learn each `xs:element` - like you're already doing for the `simpleTypes` and `complexTypes` Maps - so they can later be resolved from a `ref`.

If what you need is the model of the resolved elements and types in the XML schema though, it would be worth exploring that behind the scenes schema model - in an XML Parser such as Xerces.  As a starting point, this is using XNI - the Xerces Native Interface:

```
    File baseDir = new File("/myschemas");

    XMLEntityResolver entityResolver = new XMLEntityResolver() {

        @Override
        public XMLInputSource resolveEntity(
                XMLResourceIdentifier resourceIdentifier)
                throws XNIException, IOException {
            // E.g. resourceIdentifier.getLiteralSystemId() will be segments.xsd
            String uri = new File(baseDir,
                    resourceIdentifier.getLiteralSystemId()).toURI()
                    .toString();
            return new XMLInputSource(null, uri, null);
        }
    };
    XMLSchemaLoader loader = new XMLSchemaLoader();
    loader.setEntityResolver(entityResolver);

    XSModel model = loader
            .loadURI(new File(baseDir, "messages.xsd").toURI()
                    .toString());

    System.out.println(model.getComponents(XSConstants.ELEMENT_DECLARATION));
```

This outputs such as:

```
{http://www.xsd_porcessor.org/parser}ADT.A01="http://www.xsd_porcessor.org/parser":ADT.A01
```

Comment: I am using Java 8. I am trying to avoid using extra libraries. Is there a way to accomplish what I need with just parsers provided by Java 8 API?

Comment: In fact the built-in XML parser in Java 8 etc is an old fork of Xerces, just that the internal package names are different to avoid colliding with the 'real' Xerces.  E.g. `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader` instead of `org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader`.  The example above works fine unmodified, just with the alternative `import` statements.  For reference, I should mention that common guidance is to use Xerces instead of the built-in XML parser, as the JDK fork is reputed to be a bit buggy.  I've not personally hit any problems with it though.